# Wildcard character available in asp classic?

Tags: if-statement, vbscript, asp-classic, wildcard, http-referer

I'm got a site with classic asp using vbscript. How can I check if a user is coming from a certain directory on my site? I've got this code

```
<%Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables("http_referer"))%>
```

which writes: http://example.com/mobile/REFER.asp. I'd like to write an if/else statement that first checks if the referring uri is in the directory http://example.com/mobile/.

So my code should be something like the below. But I'm not sure about syntax. Is there such a thing as a wildcard character is asp?

```
<% Request.ServerVariables("http_referer") == "http://example.com/mobile/*"
```

Eventually I'd like to use that to write an if /else statement

```
<% if Request.ServerVariables("http_referer") != "http://example.com/mobile/*" then 
null; elseif (screen.width <= 699) {
    document.location = "/mobile/mobile_home.asp";
  } %>
```

===

Ended up editing @mikeyq6's javascript sample to this which works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.referrer.indexOf('/mobile') > -1 &&
    screen.width <= 699) {
    document.location = "/mobile/mobile_home.asp";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Bear in mind that any approach that uses a hard coded URL isn't the best idea especially from a maintenance point of view. If you do need to do this consider storing in URL you wish to check inside an [Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525360(v=vs.90).aspx) object level variable, that way you can define it once inside `global.asa` and call it when required.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you are dealing with is a string, so you can't use wildcards in this way (unless you were to use regular expressions, which is like hitting a nail with a sledgehammer in this case)

It would be much easier to use the `InStr` function to check to see if the value contains the string you are looking for. Eg:

```
<% if InStr(Request.ServerVariables("http_referer"), "http://example.com/mobile/") = 0 then
    null
elseif (screen.width <= 699) {
    document.location = "/mobile/mobile_home.asp";
} %>
```

More info on `InStr` here:
http://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_instr.asp

You can do something similar in javascript as well:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("http://example.com/mobile/") > -1 &&
    screen.width <= 699) {

    document.location = "/mobile/mobile_home.asp";
}
```

Notice that I simplified the `if...else` as well. You don't need both cases.

Comment: Oops. So apparently I mixed both asp and javascript. Is there a javascript equivalent for InStr(Request.ServerVariables("http_referer")?

Comment: @user5753132 I added an example in javascript at the bottom of the answer

Answer (score 0):

You know the length of the fixed url you are looking for so just see if the first n characters of the referer match it:

```
const BASE_DIR = "http://example.com/mobile/"

dim referer: referer = lcase(Request.ServerVariables("http_referer"))

if left(referer, len(BASE_DIR)) = BASE_DIR then
    ...
else
    ...
end if
```